# Is this relation reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric, transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> There is relation
>
> $$R=\left\{(1,1),(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(5,4)\right\}$$
>
> What properties (see title) it have?

Hi maths people I learn for test next week. Here is my idea is it good or not?

-not reflexive because we don't have $(2,2)$ as example

-not irreflexive because we have for example $(1,1)$

-not symmetric because for example $(1,5)$ exists but no $(5,1)$

-not asymmetric because for example $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ exist

-not antisymmetric because for example $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ exist but they are not equal

But no idea is transitive very complicated.. Is trick to check it easy pls tell me?

And is my reasons good and correct?

Comment: Use the transitive property on $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your answers (and reasons given!) so far are correct!

Transitivity means that whenever you have $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$, you should also have $(a,c)$.  What do you think: do you have that here?

Comment: Hi Bram I always see you here thank you for confirmed!!! :)

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren Bram answered everything the OP didn't; what's missing?

Comment: @Bram28 I was too quick... it looks just fine now :D

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren OK, thanks! :)

Comment: @Hamudii You're welcome ... do you think it's transitive?

Comment: I simply saw an unupdated version of the answer.

Comment: @Bram28 When I use what you say I find it's no transitive because $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ we have $a=2$ and $b=4$ and $c=2$ then $(a,c)=(2,2)$ no exist in the set?

Comment: @Hamudii yes, very good!  You can also point to $(1,5)$ and $(5,4)$, but no $(1,4)$.